# Failed to run ansible playbook with gather_facts true

Tags: ansible

My ansible playbook will fail if i set gather_facts to true.
Even I execute ansible-cmdb , i will get the same issue.

The full traceback is:

```
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_setup_payload_ccUPIO/ansible_setup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2848, in run_command
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1238, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

QA_SILVER_MANUAL_LARGE(19.01GA_repo)_IDM | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/facter --puppet --json", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "fact_path": "/etc/ansible/facts.d", 
            "filter": "*", 
            "gather_subset": [
                "all"
            ], 
            "gather_timeout": 10
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "[Errno 13] Permission denied", 
    "rc": 13
}
```

and here was my ansible version info:

```
bash-4.2# ansible --version
ansible 2.7.5
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ara/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug 31 2018, 05:35:17) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36.0.1)]
```

Can you please kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double-check your installation. The warning says:

> File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py"

but *ansible --version* reports:

> python version = 2.7.5